# R) Using join in R

Tags: sql, r, join, left-join, inner-join

Given database is down below,

```
> dbReadTable(jamesdb, "EMPLOYEE")
  EMP_NO NI_NO  NAME AGE DEPT_NO
1     E1   123 SMITH  21      D1
2     E2   159 SMITH  31      D1
3     E3  5432 BROWN  65      D2
4     E5  7654 GREEN  52      D3

> dbReadTable(jamesdb, "DEPARTMENT")
  DEPT_NO     NAME MANAGER
1      D1 Accounts      E1
2      D2   Stores      E3
3      D3    Sales      E5

> dbReadTable(jamesdb, "PRODUCT")
  PROD_NO   NAME COLOR
1      p1  PANTS  BLUE
2      p2  PANTS KHAKI
3      p3  SOCKS GREEN
4      p4  SOCKS WHITE
5      p5 SHIRTS WHITE

> dbReadTable(jamesdb, "STOCK_TOTAL")
  PROD_NO QUANTITY
1      p1     2000
2      p2     1000
3      p3     1500
4      p4      200
5      p5      800
```

---

And down below is what I got so far but I think I have a misunderstanding of using join.
How should I fix them?

4. Retrieve the employment number of the sales department manager.

   ```
    dbGetQuery(jamesdb, 'SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMP_NO FROM DEPARTMENT JOIN EMPLOYEE
               WHERE DEPARTMENT.NAME = "Sales"')
   ```
5. Who works in Department D2?

   ```
    dbGetQuery(jamesdb, 'SELECT MANAGER FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPT_NO = "D2"')
   ```
6. How many white-colored products are in stock?

   ```
    dbGetQuery(jamesdb, 'SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM PRODUCT JOIN STOCK_TOTAL
               WHERE PRODUCT.COLOR = "WHITE"')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Joins are typically done matching one (or more) fields from one table with a corresponding field(s) of another table. For instance, I'm inferring that `DEPARTMENT.MANAGER` is actually a foreign key to `EMPLOYEE.EMP_NO`, so when you join, you should be very specific about that relationship:

```sql
SELECT e.EMP_NO
FROM DEPARTMENT d
  LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE e on d.MANAGER = e.EMP_NUM
WHERE d.NAME = "Sales"
```

Notes:

- Many databases *allow* you to be sloppy, where they will *infer* field associations (foreign keys) based on common field names. First, I don't like allowing that inference; second, it doesn't work here.
- I personally prefer to be explicit about the type of join, whether `left join`, `inner join`, etc. It's a style, you may choose just `join` if you prefer.
- I'm introducing table aliases here (`d` and `e`), a way to shorten long table names. However, they are stylistic, not required.
- I personally dislike databases that lack a dictionary of foreign keys and have unintuitive names to associate them. For instance, I'm *inferring* from the contents of the tables that `DEPARTMENT.MANAGER` is linked to `EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM`. If I'm wrong on this inference, then answers below are likely skewed.

For your first question, though, I don't know why you need a join: since `MANAGER` is already the employee number, this should be simply

```sql
select d.MANAGER
from DEPARTMENT d
where d.NAME='Sales'
```

Similarly, your second question needs no join.

```sql
select e.*
from EMPLOYEE e
where e.DEPT_NO='D2'
```

The last one needs a join, and can be done in a number of ways. One such is:

```sql
select sum(case when st.Quantity > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count
from STOCK_TOTAL st
  left join PRODUCT pr on st.PROD_NO=pr.PROD_NO
where pr.COLOR='WHITE'
```